# Spotfire 6.0 - Limit Data by Selection from Another Table

Tags: data-visualization, spotfire

I have two data tables A & B in a visualization. They can be joined by a common column ID.
Is it possible that the data chart from table B be limited by selection from table A?

Best Regards,
Jonathan

Answer (score 4):

you can create a relationship based on that ID:

1. click **Edit...Data Table Properties**
2. click the **Relations** tab
3. click **New** to create a new relation
4. configure the relation by selecting the left and right tables, the column containing the ID on both table, and optionally a method to apply to values in that column
5. click OK a few times to accept all changes

...and then configure the Filtering panel to show this relationship:

6. open the *Filtering Panel* by clicking the button on the toolbar or **View...Filters**
7. find the header for your Table B and click the "Filtering" icon next to the expansion arrow (▼)
8. select **Filtering in Table A ►** and tick **Include**

now when you change filters on Table A, data will be limited in Table B to reflect it. only the currently-selected Filtering Scheme will behave like this; any other schemes will also need to be configured (steps 6-8).

Comment: Thank you for your information. I would also like to know whether the same thing can be done for marking? Can content in Table B be limited by marking from Table A? Thanks!

Comment: Go to visualization properties (Table B in your case) and select Data on left. Then select marking which you would like to use for filtering in Limit data using markings menu.