# creating scatter plot from cross table spotfire

Tags: scatter-plot, crosstab, spotfire

Is there a way to do this in Spotfire?  I want to be able to create a scatter plot from a cross table view of a data table.  The way that I set up the cross table would result in 2 columns of data that I'd like to plot against each other.  I have been looking for a while to no avail.

Example data would be like:

```
var1  var2  values
A1    B1    x
A1    B2    y
A2    B1    z
A2    B2    a
```

The cross table view is set up like this:

```
    B1  B2
A1  x   y
A2  z   a
```

I would like to now make a scatter plot of B1 vs B2.  Somehow this is far more difficult in Spotfire than I thought it would be, as Spotfire does not treat the cross table as another data table but a view (if I understand this correctly).

Best,

Ken

Comment: The tables don't seem to be formatted correctly.  But the example provided is a 4x3 matrix and the cross table is a 2x2 matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're correct that a cross table is a "virtual" view of an existing table, not an actual copy/new table.

you can create a new table as a cross table by...

1. File » Add Data Tables...
2. click **Add ▼** and choose the existing table (under the heading **From Current Analysis**)
3. at the bottom of this dialog, click **Show Transformations**
4. **Add** a new *Pivot* transformation
5. configure the pivot as you like. in your case, I think the Row Identifier would be `[var1]`, Column Titles `[var2]`, and Values will be `[values]`. if you don't need any aggregation for `[values]`, choose the *First()* aggregation method
6. accept all changes and build the scatterplot using this new table

Comment: great! glad I could help :) would you mind marking the answer as correct, please?

Comment: As a followup question, when I do the pivot transformation, is there a way to establish a relationship between the original datatable and the new cross table?  i.e. I would like to make it such that when I filter in the original table for var2, the cross table also changes with it.  Somehow, this filtering mechanism works really easily for var1 but not var2.  Any ideas?

Comment: How do you mark the answer as correct?  I'm a noob to SO.

Comment: thanks! :) for the table relationship, I've answered a similar question with detailed steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28700078/4419423 . that should get you sorted!

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the relationship with the link!  It isn't exactly what I had in mind.  As you can see in my OP, after cross tabulation, var1 becomes the new rows and var2 becomes the new columns.  Establishing a new relation between var1 (i.e. the rows) by selecting a column is just as you described.  But to establish a new relation with var2 (that has been transposed to columns) is not so obvious to me.  Is there built-in functionality for it?

Comment: ohh sorry, I didn't catch that! I'm not sure I understand what your expected result is -- maybe I'm hung up on your sample data and it's different than your actual? my thinking is that if you remove/filter out a column, your scatter plot (two-dimensional plot) turns into more of a bar chart (one-dimensional plot). maybe it's best to use a different chart to visualize this?

Comment: Thanks Niko.  That is indeed the case.  I have more levels than the toy data that I showed.  My var2 actually has 10000 different levels.  What I'd like to do is to select some data points from the original data table (i.e. B1 and B2) and have the cross table only display B1 and B2 and the scatter point automatically updates to reflect the new filter.

Comment: I think this might be better suited to another question; the comments don't allow for a whole lot of formatting :) if I understand, your new pivoted table has columns for `[B1] [B2] [B3] ... [Bn]`? and you want the user to be able to decide to plot any two given `[Bx]` columns?